# Why is an empty file with the name of folder inside a Azure Blob storage container is created?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am running a Hive QL through HD Insight on-demand cluster which does the following

1. Spool the data from a hive view
2. Create a folder by name **abcd** inside a Blob storage container
   named XYZ
3. Store the view data in a file inside the **abcd** folder

However, when the hive QL is run,  there is an empty file with the name **abcd**   that is getting created outside the **abcd** folder

Any idea why this is happening and how do we stop it from happening. Please suggest

Thanks,

Surya

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with blob storage mounted to a spark clustering databricks.

It seems to be triggered by accessing (or writing to, both happened) the dbfs through sh or shutil instead of going through dbutils.

Anyone knows why his happens? And how to prevent?

The empty files are not visible via sh so maybe it is linked to how the kernel handles filesystem actions?

Comment: i also bothered by this issue, and we are using it in spark, and this issue breaks our spark history server with the empty file name along the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You get this because the Azure storage you are mounting does not have a hierarchical file system. For example, the mount is a blob storage of type `StorageV2` but you have not ticked the *Use hierarchical filesystem* at creation time. A version 2 blob with hierarchical file system is known as Azure Data Lake Storage generation 2 (ADLS Gen2), where they basically get rid of the blob - lake difference you had with ADLS Gen 1 vs older blob generations.

According to the blob API you are using, a number of tricks are used to give you the illusion of a hierarchical FS even when you don't have one. Like creating empty files, or hidden ones. The main is that the hierarchy is flat (i.e. there is none), so you can't just create an empty folder, you have to put something there.

For example, if you mount a v2 blob with the `wasbs://` driver in Databricks, and you do a `mkdir -p /dbfs/mnt/mymount/this/is/a/path` from a `%sh` cell you will see something like this:

- `this` folder, `this` empty file
- `this/is` folder, `this/is` empty file
- etc.

Finally, while this is perfectly *file* for Azure blob itself, it might cause trouble to anything else not expecting it, even `%sh ls`.

Just recreate the storage as ADLS Gen2, or update it live enabling the hierarchical FS.

Thanks,